# Iterate on autofiltered visible cells on VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to do something weird, and it's maybe not the only way, and it's probably the wrong one. I want to iterate on the visible cells (which is the result of the AutoFilter function of VBA).

Here's what I've done before, and it works, but not how I want :
 `Sheets("MySheet").Range("$A$3:$AI$10191").AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:=myList, Operator:=xlFilterValues` . myList is a list of String, like this : `Dim myList() as String` 
 Currently, this does not fit with what I want : I do not want this to take the blank cells, and I also want the myList() content be taken approximativly (something like "*"&myList&"*").

To do that, I tried one simple line of code and it works : 
 `Sheets("MySheet").Range("$A$3:$AI$10191").AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:="*"&myList(0)&"*", Operator:=xlFilterValues`

**My problem is** : I want to do that for all the elements of my list. I've been thinking about iterating through my list (myList) but **everytime I'm doing a new iteration, it simply does not take the result of the previous iteration** . **In reality, I just want to filter on the "already filtered" rows...** 
I already tried the method with `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` but it takes all the cells, and not only the visible one.... (here's the full code with visible cells : `Sheets("MySheet").Range("$A$3:$AI$10191").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:="*"&myList(0)&"*", Operator:=xlFilterValues`)

I've been thinking on something like that :

```
For i =0 to UBound(myList)
    Sheets("MySheet").Range("$A$3:$AI$10191").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:="*"&myList(i)&"*", Operator:=xlFilterValues
Next i
```

But it just filters following the last `.AutoFilter` rule. (it filters on `i=UBound(myList)` , because each .AutoFilter is erasing the job of the previous one... )

If you have any ideas... Thanks, Clément.

Comment: Consider using the Advanced filter instead. On a separate sheet, in column A, place the header of column 12 in A1 and below that put all the criteria strings with wild card and use advanced filter with option xlFilterInPlace.

Comment: @sktneer (for others, see his answer below)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To try the Advanced Filter, you can give this a try.
Tweak it as required...

```
Sub AdvancedFilter()
Dim wsData As Worksheet, wsCriteria As Worksheet
Dim myList() As String
Dim i As Long, lr As Long
Dim Rng As Range, Cell As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set wsData = Sheets("MySheet")
If wsData.FilterMode Then wsData.ShowAllData
lr = wsData.UsedRange.Rows.Count

On Error Resume Next
Set wsCriteria = Sheets("Criteria")
wsCriteria.Cells.Clear
On Error GoTo 0

If wsCriteria Is Nothing Then
    Sheets.Add.Name = "Criteria"
    Set wsCriteria = ActiveSheet
End If

'Assuming myList has already been populated

'Writing the column header (column 12) on Criteria Sheet in A1
wsCriteria.Cells(1, 1) = wsData.Cells(1, 12)

'Adding wild card to each element in myList
For i = 1 To UBound(myList)
    myList(i) = "*" & myList(i) & "*"
Next i

'Writing myList on Criteria Sheet
wsCriteria.Range("A2").Resize(UBound(myList)).Value = Application.Transpose(myList)

'Using Advanced Filter on Data Sheet with Criteria on Criteria Sheet
wsData.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.AdvancedFilter xlFilterInPlace, wsCriteria.Range("A1").CurrentRegion

'Deleting the Criteria Sheet as it is not required now
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
wsCriteria.Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

'Setting Rng as visible cells in column A
On Error Resume Next
Set Rng = wsData.Range("A2:A" & lr).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
    For Each Cell In Rng
        'Do your stuff here with visible range
    Next Cell
End If
If wsData.FilterMode Then wsData.ShowAllData
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey. Thanks for your answer. I'll try your idea tomorrow, it seems to be a quite good idea. Perhaps a little bit "too much" (creating a new sheet, adding it values, ...). Anyway, thanks.

Comment: Re, I don't understand those lines : `wsData.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.AdvancedFilter xlFilterInPlace, wsCriteria.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
` and also `'Do your stuff here with visible range` . The first line isn't working on my computer. I just don't undersand why we are using the wsData.Range("A1"). What's the goal of that ? Thanks

Comment: The code assumes that the data on Data sheet starts from Row2 and Row1 being the header row. So wsData.Range("A1").CurrentRegion means the advanced filter is applied to whole data on the Data sheet. When the advanced filter is applied, the rows which do not match with the criteria become invisible and only rows which meet the criteria in column L are visible. Do your stuff means if you want to further loop through the visible data, you can do so inside the loop.

Comment: That doesn't work on my computer. I'm sorry, thanks for your help. There's no error, but it doesn't do what I want (currently it's filtering absolutely all, like I've absolutly nothing after that sample of code ) : `wsData.Range("B3").CurrentRegion.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:=wsCriteria.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
`   Indeed, on my criteria sheet, I have on A1 : name of column, A2 and A3 and ... the name of the criterias. Moreover, on my data sheet, my data starts at B3 with the column names, and finish on something like "AG10100" ...

Comment: wsData.Range("B3").CurrentRegion.AdvancedFilter will work if row2 is blank otherwise the filter will not be applied to Row3. To overcome this issue, declare a variable to hold the last row used with data and then instead of currentregion try wsData.Range("A2:AG" & lr).AdvancedFilter OR wsData.Range("A2:AG10100").AdvancedFilter

Comment: Yeah, it works ! I inserted a new row on row 3 (an empty one). Thanks for all. Clément

Comment: Can you share the sample workbook to find the issue? Remember the proposed code assumes that the criteria column is column L.

Comment: It works. I just forgot to remove the `wsData.ShowAllData` on my last try of your idea. Thanks, Clément

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144470/discussion-between-clement-b-and-sktneer).

Comment: @ClementB What was that? Why you unaccepted the answer?